Запятые между определениями
Интересует постановка запятых между определениями в следующих предложениях.

Особо впечатляют невероятного масштаба(,) явно рукотворные(,) горные хребты в Забайкалье.

Каким-то очень мощным воздействием были разрушены огромные мегалитические(,) одинаковой правильной формы(,) блоки крепостей и уникальных построек.


Если первые запятые вроде бы нужны, то насчет вторых сомневаюсь. Спасибо.

Правильно (выбираем вариант):

Особо впечатляют невероятного масштаба, явно рукотворные, горные хребты в Забайкалье.

Каким-то очень мощным воздействием были разрушены огромные мегалитические, одинаковой правильной формы, блоки крепостей и уникальных построек.


Пояснение
ТЕОРИЯ

Несколько определений, относящихся к одному существительному, могут находиться в однородных, неоднородных или уточняющих отношениях, что соответствует разной постановке знаков.

Но четкой границы между этими определениями нет, и одни отношения могут без особого труда переходить в другие. Неоднородные отношения сближаются с однородными, раскрывая одну тему, а уточнение зависит не только от значения, но и от желания автора отнести определение на второй план, что во многом определяется структурой предложения.

Тему уточняющих определений регулирует правило Розенталя § 22. Уточняющие члены предложения, пункт 4. Там приведено большое количество примеров, где встречаются определения разного вида и значения. Нужно обращать внимание на вид определения: качественное или относительное, согласованное или несогласованное, а также учитывать смысловое значение слова.

РЕШЕНИЕ ЗАДАЧИ

Особо впечатляют невероятного масштаба, явно рукотворные, горные хребты в Забайкалье.

На первом месте находится несогласованное определение, далее оборот и относительное прилагательное.
Исходный вариант: Особо впечатляют невероятного масштаба горные хребты в Забайкалье.
Это неоднородные отношения определений разного вида, запятую здесь не поставишь. Поэтому вписать в эту конструкцию оборот можно только в виде уточнения.

Каким-то очень мощным воздействием были разрушены огромные мегалитические, одинаковой правильной формы, блоки крепостей и уникальных построек.

Исходный вариант: Каким-то очень мощным воздействием были разрушены огромные мегалитические блоки крепостей и уникальных построек.
Отношения неоднородные (качественное и относительное прилагательное), а оборот значительно распространен. К тому же у него явно уточняющее значение по смыслу, да и по структуре он расположен непосредственно перед определяемым словом после относительного прилагательного. Поэтому требуется обособление.
Мегали́ты — сооружения из огромных каменных глыб, характерные в основном для финального неолита и энеолита (IV—III тыс. до н. э. в Европе, либо позднее в Азии и Африке).
